# Implement Map in C++ with a predefined size

Tags: c++, dictionary

I want to implement my own version of a map data structure in C++.
I need its size to be predefined so I decided that when the user creates the map he will have to specify not only the size, but also a default value for the keys and for the values.
before you ask - I need this in order to be able to use that data structore in an embedded system.

I have written this constructor:

```
template <typename T, typename K>
myMap<T, K>::myMap(int size, const T& keyInit, const K& valueInit) :
size(nSize), defaultKey(keyInit), defaultValue(valueInit)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < nSize; i++)
    {
        container.insert(std::make_pair(keyInit,valueInit));
    }
}
```

where `container` is a member of type: `std::map<T, K>` (and basically the class is just a wrapper for the stl map)

now I'm not sure how to implement the insert function. aside from that I have figured out how to delete (reassgin default values) and how to search (use stl's maps find).
So my only problem right now is the insert method.

I thought about iterating through the map and looking for the first free cell but it got me confused and I' stuck.
Any other ideas would be great.

Comment: I think you don't understand the idea of map data structure. In map every key is unique and has only one value.

Comment: Is your conainer a std::map ?

Comment: yes, it is. as stated above

Comment: Maybe you should state your requirements re. the embedded environment, i.e. what problem you're trying to solve. Because what you're trying to do doesn't make much sense. This sounds like an X-Y problem.

Comment: Read tag descriptions before adding.

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood well, you make a wrapper for a standard container, i.e. a map.

At construction, you intend to insert several the same default key.  This is not allowed in a [`std::map`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/), where the key MUST be unique.

If you want to use several time the same key in a map, you have to use a [`multimap`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/multimap/):  you can use it almost as a map, but it allows to have duplicate keys.

I'm not sure why you create items with a default key, but you have to be aware that maps and multimaps work with ordered keys. So if you intend later to replace the default key with another one, you can't just replace the values: you have to delete the entry and insert a new one.

Comment: @wannabeprogrammer I've edited with a suggestion for a multimap and a big warning about the notion of default key in a map.

Answer (score 0):

Key in [std::map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/) is unique, so what you do at construction does not make sense.

If you seek great performance (as this may be the case in embedded world), then I would advise to find [some other hash table implementation](https://gist.github.com/tonious/1377667).
You can also implement your own hash table to meet your needs.

Comment: The hash table is a valid alternative. But instead of using the c alterative that you refer to (which is not templated and seems not to be fully compatible with object creation semantic due to the malloc), I'd rather adivse for an `unordered_multimap` which is in fact implementad a hash table.  The main issue remains however: even in a hashtable, you can't just iterate through the table and just replace the first default key that you find with another key value.

Comment: There are two main ways to implement hash table: maintain linked list in every bucket or just use next bucket if the one returned by hash function is occupied. In the second implementation we need to predefine the size of value table and it won't get bigger.

Comment: @wannabeprogrammer: It depends on how you will use the structure, it may be better if you don't need to refer to values by key or you don't seek O(1) complexity for accessing elements and O(n) is enough.

Answer (score 0):

For an embedded system what I think you *actually* want is custom memory allocators. You can define an allocation pool for each data structure you want to use. Then you pass it to the constructor for the map and it will allocate data from the pool. When the pool is empty it will send out `bad_alloc` exceptions.